# Add username and password to root user in mongo docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, hosting

I have a Spring Boot app deployed with docker-compose. My MongoDB database got hacked, luckily it is a side project.

I want to be able to deploy the app with a **password set for the root user**. I already have a user for the database but is not the root one. Right now if I connect using MongoDB Compass or using SSH, the server does not request a password to query the DB.

I tried using

```
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

But it's not setting the user and pass for the root user.

Here's my `.yml` file

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ../client/build:/www
      - ./nginx/conf/default.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    networks:
      - main-network

  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '27027:27017'
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=transport
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db/
      - ./mongo/log:/var/log/mongodb/
      - ./mongo/init/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js
    networks:
      - main-network

  booking-server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: booking-server
    container_name: booking-server
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./log:/log
      - ./application.properties:/application.properties
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    networks:
      - main-network

networks:
  main-network:
```

mongo-init.js

```
db.createUser({user: "admin", pwd: "password", roles : [{role: "readWrite", db: "transport"}]});
```

Comment: If this is a _deployed_ application, would it work for you to delete the `ports:` for the services other than the main proxy, so that they're not network-accessible?  Connections between containers don't use or require `ports:` so the application internally should work file.

Comment: So in that case, would I be able to connect using MongoDB compass and the admin user created in mongo-init.js ?

Comment: Not from outside Docker space.  But I'd probably discourage directly accessing the database in a deployed application in any case.

Comment: Got it. I tried and the server is failing to connect to the database without the ports set in docker-compose.yml

Comment: @DavidMaze I had to change application.properties because it was accessing the DB using IP and Port instead of using spring.data.mongodb.host

You can write the comment as an answer if you want. Thank you, I spent 2 days debugging this.